# How to fetch Declarative Metadata i.e. meta.xml file with Tooling API query?

Tags: apex, soap-api, metadata-api, tooling-api

Is there a way to fetch the meta.xml file via tooling api query?
The meta.xml looks like this for apex class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

and for pages it looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <availableInTouch>false</availableInTouch>
    <confirmationTokenRequired>false</confirmationTokenRequired>
    <label>ContactDeails</label>
</ApexPage>
```

How can I fetch them via query ? Or which API should I use to fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve equivalent *information* from the Tooling API, but if what you want is the on-disk format Metadata API source code, just perform a retrieve with the Metadata API.

You'd do that by calling [`retrieve()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm) to [retrieve a ZIP file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based_zip_file.htm), supplying a package manifest (`package.xml` file or the data-structure equivalent). You can then unpack the ZIP file to get the same `-meta.xml` file that you would when using any Salesforce IDE.

Since there are many extant Metadata API clients (Salesforce DX, Workbench, various IDEs...) you may not even need to write any code to do this, depending on your specific use case.

## Tooling API

Review the [Tooling API object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexpage.htm) to identify the location of the relevant data points in Tooling API response objects. The above link is for `ApexPage`, the Visualforce page entity; you'll note that that object contains the properties `ApiVersion`, `IsAvailableInTouch`, `IsConfirmationTokenRequired`, and `MasterLabel`, just like the `-meta.xml` file does. You can include these points in your Tooling API queries against the `ApexPage` object.

You can reconstruct the Metadata API-format XML source from this data, but it's easier just to get it from the Metadata API in the first place *unless* you only need the data, not the XML file.

Comment: `You can retrieve equivalent information from the Tooling API` how can I achieve this? Is there a query?

Comment: @NagendraSingh I've expanded my answer. No, there isn't a single query that will return that specific XML, but the contained data points should be available through the Tooling API at least in many cases (I don't know if coverage is exactly 1:1).

Comment: @NagendraSingh The Tooling API only has enough functionality as needed for IDE Development. This means many metadata types wouldn't be available for use compared to the Metadata API. As David says, you'll need to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks, yes understood, I was using tooling api for most of my operations, such as generating symbol table etc. But now I think I have to check metadata api too.